# Why do I get initiator of CollectSignaturesFlow must pass in exact sessions error in Corda?

Tags: corda

I am making a CorDapp that involves two parties - a Client and an Underwriter. I have two main flows, one being IssuePolicy and another being PayoutPolicy. When I run each flow once, there are no issues. When I run IssuePolicy again, I receive the error: `The Initiator of CollectSignaturesFlow must pass in exactly the sessions required to sign the transaction.` I've already searched Stack Overflow and found this post: [Flow Exception in CollectSignaturesFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51064153/flow-exception-in-collectsignaturesflow) but I believe I have signed with one party and initiated flow with the other, so I am not sure whether this solution applies to me. Any help would be appreciated!

IssuePolicy Flow:

```
        // Step 3. Building.
        progressTracker.currentStep = BUILDING
        val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities[0]
        val utx = TransactionBuilder(notary = notary)
                .addOutputState(policy, INSUREFLIGHT_CONTRACT_ID)
                .addCommand(InsureFlightContract.Commands.Issue(), policy.participants.map { it.owningKey })
                .setTimeWindow(serviceHub.clock.instant(), 30.seconds)

        // Stage 4. Get some cash from the vault and add a spend to our transaction builder.
        // We pay cash to the underwriter's policy key.
        val (_, cashSigningKeys) = Cash.generateSpend(serviceHub, utx, premium, underwriter)
        check(cashSigningKeys == cashSigningKeys){
            throw FlowException("")
        }
        // Step 5. Sign the transaction.
        progressTracker.currentStep = SIGNING
        val ptx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(utx, policy.client.owningKey)

        // Step 6. Get the counter-party signature.
        progressTracker.currentStep = COLLECTING
        val otherpartySession = initiateFlow(underwriter)
        val stx = subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(
                ptx,
                listOf(otherpartySession),
                COLLECTING.childProgressTracker())
        )

        // Step 7. Finalize the transaction.
        progressTracker.currentStep = FINALIZING
        return subFlow(FinalityFlow(stx, FINALIZING.childProgressTracker()))
    }
}

// Allows counterparty to respond.
@InitiatedBy(Initiator::class)
class IssuePolicyResponder(val otherPartySession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
@Suspendable
override fun call() {
    val signTransactionFlow = object : SignTransactionFlow(otherPartySession, SignTransactionFlow.tracker()) {
        override fun checkTransaction(stx: SignedTransaction) = requireThat {
        }
    }

    subFlow(signTransactionFlow)
}
}
}
```

Policy State Definition:

```
//Policy Class, includes premium, claim, client, underwriter, flight, and policyID
data class Policy(val premium: Amount<Currency>,
              val claim: Amount<Currency>,
              val client: Party,
              val underwriter: Party,
              val flight: String,
              override val linearId: UniqueIdentifier = UniqueIdentifier()) : LinearState {

//Get clients and underwriters
override val participants: List<Party> get() = listOf(client, underwriter)

//Functions to update policy parameters
fun payPremium(amountToPay: Amount<Currency>) = copy(premium = premium + amountToPay)
fun payClaim(amountToPay: Amount<Currency>) = copy(claim = claim + amountToPay)
fun withNewClient(newClient: Party) = copy(client = newClient)
fun withNewUnderwriter(newUnderwriter: Party) = copy(underwriter = newUnderwriter)
fun withNewFlight(newFlight: String) = copy(flight = newFlight)

//Provides response
override fun toString(): String {
    val clientString = (client as? Party)?.name?.organisation ?: client.owningKey.toBase58String()
    val underwriterString = (underwriter as? Party)?.name?.organisation ?: underwriter.owningKey.toBase58String()
    return "Policy($linearId): $clientString has paid a premium of $$premium for flight $flight, underwritten by $underwriterString with" +
            "a claim amount of $$claim."
}
}
```

Commands in the Contract:

```
interface Commands : CommandData {
    class Issue : TypeOnlyCommandData(), Commands
    class Settle : TypeOnlyCommandData(), Commands
}

override fun verify(tx: LedgerTransaction): Unit {
    val command = tx.commands.requireSingleCommand<Commands>()
    val setOfSigners = command.signers.toSet()
    when (command.value) {
        is Commands.Issue -> verifyIssue(tx, setOfSigners)
        is Commands.Settle -> verifySettle(tx, setOfSigners)
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unrecognized command. You can only issue or settle.")
    }
}
```

Comment: The required signers will depend on the commands. Can you extend the IssuePolicy flow to show how you create and add the commands?

Comment: I have added them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all the cash in your node's vault will be owned by your node's main public key. This is because when `Cash.generateSpend` generates change outputs, this change is assigned to a new confidential identity instead of your node's main identity for privacy reasons.

This is the purpose of the `cashSigningKeys` returned by `Cash.generateSpend`. It's a list of the public keys that own all the cash added to the transaction builder by `Cash.generateSpend`.

I'm guessing that the first time you run `IssuePolicy`/`PayoutPolicy`, it generates some cash owned by a new confidential identity. You never sign the transaction with the key of the new confidential identity. Effectively, it is this confidential identity's session that is missing when you call `CollectSignaturesFlow`.

Of course, it doesn't make sense to create a session with this confidential identity, since it actually corresponds to the node running the flow. Instead, you need to take the `cashSigningKeys` returned by `Cash.generateSpend`, and sign the transaction with these as well before calling `CollectSignaturesFlow`, by calling:

```
val ptx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(
    utx, 
    cashSigningKeys + policy.client.owningKey)
```